# What is the difference between multiple class properties and single class list with multiple classes?

Tags: css, class

In CSS styles, when two classes with same weight, the later declared one will overwrite the previous one, just as following code

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h1.first  {color:blue;}
h1.second {color:cyan;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="first second">The heading text</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

switching '**first**' and '**second**' will not impact the final '**cyan**' color. While when I try to split the class list into multiple classes, seems the order will impact the final result, for example, when using

```
<h1 class="first" class="second">The heading text</h1>
```

The final color is '**blue**', when using

```
<h1 class="second" class="first">The heading text</h1>
```

The final color is '**cyan**'

Could anyone give a more detail description about the difference? It seems if I split class list, only the first class attribute will work? seems the split one will not merge into one single class list. Thanks.

Comment: There should only be one `class` attribute for a given element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The element can only have one `class` attribute. So when you add two, the second one is ignored, which is why you get that behaviour.

Note: The fact that the second one is ignored is a browser specific implementation. I'm not aware of browsers that do it differently, but basically the document is invalid and browsers can 'solve' this any way they want.

[The HTML Syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0) says that multiple attributes with the same name should never exist on the same element, but it doesn't say how to solve this, so that's up to the browser vendors.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can only define an attribute on an element once per HTML standards and as @GolezTrol explained, the specification does not say how to handle and therefor most browsers just ignore the second declaration of class="xxx" altogether.

```
<h1 class="first second">The heading text</h1>
```

This will always be cyan because of how the CSS declarations are defined. You have second defined after first and according to the [specification, the latter rule overrides the former.](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade).

The specification states as the 4th rule under 6.4.1 Cascading order:

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same
>   weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins.
>   Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any
>   declarations in the style sheet itself

So if you switch the definition, like so:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
h1.second {color:cyan;}
h1.first  {color:blue;}

</style>
</head>
```

Then the color will be defined as blue instead of cyan.

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

They way you can write multiple class in an element is like this:

```
<h1 class="first second">The heading text</h1>
```

If you are styling the same property with 2 classes, the last class will prevail and the other one will be ignored.